# How to hard throw IndexOutOfBoundsException for RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have small chance (0,5% users in day if trust fabric crashreport) catch `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detecte`d in two method for `RecyclerView` (i see crashlog in fabric ):

- validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition()
- tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline()

I search same issue in other cases and i realized that this problem may occur when retrieving and updating data in the adapter from different threads. I fix this problem stupedly, but in theory this can work correctly:

```
    private fun setUpdates() {
                //...

                //fix code start
                if (Looper.getMainLooper().thread == Thread.currentThread()) {
                    log("thread is main")
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                } else {
                    log("thread NOT is main")
                    notifyOnUi()
                }
                //fix code end

                //...
            }

    private fun notifyOnUi() {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            log("notify data set changes on UI")
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

And i don't know how Hard reproduce situation when this exception throws. I tried different options with multiple threads modify the list before/after/during `adapter.notifyDataSetChanges()` but this problem not reproduces (without fix code).

And mu question - what can we do that would throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. ...` for two methods in `RecyclerView` for test - fix my code this problem or not?:

- validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition()
- tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's the **UI Thread** that call `getItemCount()`, `onCreateViewHolder`, `onBindViewHolder`, etc... methods of the adapter.

So, if a different thread modify the *data* used by these methods, *inconsistency* can appear. Because, the data is not up-to-date with the notifications (`notifyDataSetChanged`, etc...).

For not having any inconsistencies, you have to modify the data and call `notifyDataSetChanged` in the same [message](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a) posted on the main thread.

Something like:

```
private fun setUpdates(newData: Collection<Data>) {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        myData = newData // or whatever
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // and notify within the same message
    }
}
```

Comment: i understand you) but i don't know how `reproduce` this problem in my code. I tried create many threads and modify data - and i not throws this Exception.

Comment: This is a race condition... Very hard to reproduce. But I had the same issue, change my code for using UI Thread, see the issue disappear from Crashlytics!